# Undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

Sometimes I get this error, and I just want Rails to rescue/skip the error when it happens rather than stop the program completely. Is there a good way to do this?

Below is my code:

```
<% wiki = MediaWiki.new(:domain => 'commons.wikimedia.org') %>
<% wikimedia_user = wiki.find("File:Samuel_L_Jackson_as_Nick_Fury.jpg") %>
```

The second line causes this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass)
```

If that happens, I just want `wikimedia_user` to be set to nil. I tried adding `.inspect?` to the end of the `.find`, but all I get is the error. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the same line as the one you want to suppress the exception and return nil on, add `rescue nil` to the end.

```
<% wikimedia_user = wiki.find("File:Samuel_L_Jackson_as_Nick_Fury.jpg") rescue nil %>
```

Note: This isn't generally considered a good practice, as any kind of exception thrown from that line will be caught by that rescue. In your case, it's probably not a big problem, but something to keep in mind moving forward.